# How to rotate an element inside a div, and the div will change its height and width base on the rotated element?

Tags: html, css

My problem is when I rotate my h2 element inside this div, the height and width stays the same. I want my div to change its height and width base on its content. The first image is without the rotation of the h2 element. The second image is where I apply the rotate transform on the h2 element.

FIRST IMAGE:
[without rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD0sr.png)

SECOND IMAGE:
[with rotate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEqw2.png)

This is my code:

HTML:

```
    <!-- Gallery Title and Nav-->
    <div class="gallery-title-and-nav">
      <!-- Gallery title -->
      <div class="gallery-title">
        <h2>GALLERY</h2>
      </div>

      <!-- gallery pciker -->
      <div class="gallery-nav">
        <h4>POSTER</h4>
        <h4>INFOGRAPHICS</h4>
        <h4>MAGAZINE 01</h4>
        <h4>MAGAZINE 02</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Gallery Title and Nav */
.gallery-title-and-nav {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    height: 60vh;
    width: fit-content;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: auto
}

.gallery-title {
    background: green;
    height: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
}

.gallery-title h2 {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.gallery-nav {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Why not rotating the `div` itself?

Comment: @mo3n when I rotate the div, the w&h also stays the same. If you overflow:hidden the div, you'll see that the hight will cut off the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with doing just a transform is that the element still has the same positioning and size as before the transform as far as the overall layout goes.

What you could use is a vertical text writing method. This is not a transform and the element will take up the dimensions:

```css
/* Gallery Title and Nav */

.gallery-title-and-nav {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  height: 60vh;
  width: fit-content;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: auto
}

.gallery-title {
  background: green;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}

.gallery-title h2 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.gallery-nav {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Gallery Title and Nav-->
<div class="gallery-title-and-nav">
  <!-- Gallery title -->
  <div class="gallery-title">
    <h2>GALLERY</h2>
  </div>

  <!-- gallery pciker -->
  <div class="gallery-nav">
    <h4>POSTER</h4>
    <h4>INFOGRAPHICS</h4>
    <h4>MAGAZINE 01</h4>
    <h4>MAGAZINE 02</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it worked for me. I learned new thing, and that is `writing-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

The mdn web docs tell that,

> The transform CSS property lets you rotate, scale, skew, or translate an element. It modifies the coordinate space of the CSS **visual formatting model.**

It means that ,your transform is seen only visually rotated,but the container predicts it as if the text is never rotated,and still horizontal

### Solution

Instead rotate the parent of it(`.gallery-title`),the child(s) will also be rotated

```css
/* Gallery Title and Nav */
.gallery-title-and-nav {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    height: 60vh;
    width: fit-content;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: auto
}

.gallery-title {
    background: green;
    height: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
}

.gallery-title{/*I HAVE CHANGED*/
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.gallery-nav {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Gallery Title and Nav-->
    <div class="gallery-title-and-nav">
      <!-- Gallery title -->
      <div class="gallery-title">
        <h2>GALLERY</h2>
      </div>

      <!-- gallery pciker -->
      <div class="gallery-nav">
        <h4>POSTER</h4>
        <h4>INFOGRAPHICS</h4>
        <h4>MAGAZINE 01</h4>
        <h4>MAGAZINE 02</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### Other issues

- Since the text is `h2`(heading) it has some margin,
  *Solution: `.gallery-title h2{ margin:0; }`*
- In `.gallery-title-and-nav`, `height: 60vh;` is relative to window, and it creates some issue
  *Solution: `height:200px;/*or anything else with unit px*/`* **or** `height:fit-content`,fit content is best and I am using it in below code

## Final answer code:

```css
/* Gallery Title and Nav */
.gallery-title-and-nav {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    height: fit-content;/*CHANGED*/
    width: fit-content;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-basis: auto
}

.gallery-title {
    background: green;
    height: fit-content;
    width: fit-content;
}

.gallery-title{/*I HAVE CHANGED*/
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.gallery-nav {
    background: blue;
}
.gallery-title h2{/*I HAVE ADDED*/
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Gallery Title and Nav-->
    <div class="gallery-title-and-nav">
      <!-- Gallery title -->
      <div class="gallery-title">
        <h2>GALLERY</h2>
      </div>

      <!-- gallery pciker -->
      <div class="gallery-nav">
        <h4>POSTER</h4>
        <h4>INFOGRAPHICS</h4>
        <h4>MAGAZINE 01</h4>
        <h4>MAGAZINE 02</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried the code that you've put in your answer, but it still treat the rotation of the div as you said "It means that ,your transform is seen only visually rotated, but the container predicts it as if the text is never rotated, and still horizontal". I got the answer now, I added the `writing-mode: vertical-lr;` on my h2 based on the other answer, and it works now. Thank you for your answer, I now knew why my problem happened. Helped a lot.